# What is a modern way in C++ to execute "mkdir -p"?

Tags: c++, filesystems, mkdir

The C++17 standard has introduced the `<filesystem>` library, which provides some facilities to perform operations on file systems, paths, files and directories. In order to create a new directory, one can use
[`create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory).

However, in case the parent directories do not exist, this function will fail, because it is equivalent to UNIX `mkdir` without flags. Whether one wants to create all parent directories in addition to the given as argument, one runs `mkdir` with flag `-p`. But the function is C++17 doesn't provide an option to add flags.

It there another way to create the whole set of directories simultaneously in C++ style?

There is a C style option with the help of `<cstdlib>`:

```
std::system("mkdir -p NEW_DIRECTORY")
```

However, if `NEW_DIRECTORY` is provided as `string`, one then before has to do something like:

```
std::string mkdir_s = "mkdir -p "s + NEW_DIRECTORY;                                     
std::system(mkdir_s.c_str());
```

Comment: I think `create_directories()` does what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) which will

> Executes (1)[create_directory] for every element of p that does not already exist. If p already exists, the function does nothing (this condition is not treated as an error).

Comment: thanks! I should be more attentive, when looking up in the documentation

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator No worries.  You're welcome.